# CSS: How to lay an image on top of a table

Tags: css, image, css-float

I have a table of figures and I want to append an image 
on top of the table on the border edges of the data. However I have no 
idea how to do this, can someone point me in the right direction?

Below is what I want to achieve:

[image]

At the moment I have the table without the round "arrow" and "=" images.

Thanks

Taking the advice below I have implemented this code:

```
<td>
<img src="images/up.png" alt="increase" height="20" width="20" style="position: relative; left: 47px;"/>&euro;<?php echo $cSalePrice; ?>
</td>
```

To give the following result:

[image]

As you can see the arrow image isn't centred to the blocks and
also the text "€65" has been nudged down...

Any ideas?

Ok now trying the commented suggestion it has fixed the "€65" nudge.
But still the image isn't vertically centered to the box:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your image should have a position absolute, top and left (or bottom right). The < td> it's in should be position relative.

So, something like:

```
<td style="position:relative;">&euro;65<img src="..." style="position:absolute; left:30px; top: 3px;"> </td>
```

This way, you can position the image relatively to the td it's in.

And you should use classes instead of inline code

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to place the `<img src="...">` in the left TD, for example, and give it the following styling to shift it right of its layout position:

```
position: relative;
left: 16px;
```

Comment: I'd rather set position: relative; to the <td> and position: absolute;  to the image. Remember to set both, top and left otherwise IE will fail on it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work. Create an extra column and make the width 0. I am using divs instead of images but it is the same. You could try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/faTdm/)

the css

```
table {
    margin: 10px;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}

table td.thin {
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}

table td.thin div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

And the html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>r1c1</td>
        <td class="thin"><div>×</div></td>
        <td>r1c3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>r2c1</td>
        <td class="thin"><div>×</div></td>
        <td>r2c3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This should ensure vertical and horizontal centering and would not affect the other cells.

Answer (score 1):

Make the table relative.

Then add four images in te table that are positioned absolutly and positioned to each of their own corners. eg:

```
table{position:relative}
table img.topright{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;}
table img.bottomleft{position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;}
```

etc